# Simple to-doList: Issue on adding "None" when list is empty, or remove it when at least one item is added. What is the better solution?

Tags: javascript, function

I am struggle to manage correctly the element with the text node "None".

The main issue of this code is the initial element with the text node "None" is not being removed after I add new Items. The expected behavior is load the page with this "None" element. When user add at least 1 item, then removed. If the list is empty, then appears "None" again.

What is the best way to fix it?

UPDATE:
Now the snippet of code is running properly. Just for better clarification: if you run this code, it works fine at first. But when I clean all the items, then "None" still appears above the other items.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#userInput"),
  button = document.querySelector("#buttonInput"),
  ul = document.querySelector("ul"),
  allLi = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function insertMessageIfListEmpty() {
  if (typeof ul.children[0] === "undefined") {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("None"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

function createListElement() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  createDeleteButtonIcon(li);
  if (allLi[0].innerHTML === "None") {
    allLi[0].remove();
  }
}

function createDeleteButtonIcon(item) {
  let i = document.createElement("i"),
    span = document.createElement("span");
  i.innerHTML = "&times";
  i.classList.add("iconX");
  span.appendChild(i);
  item.appendChild(span);
  addEventDeleteParent(item);
}

function deleteNodeOnClick(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "I") {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
  }
  insertMessageIfListEmpty();
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if(inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeyDown(event) {
    if(inputLength() > 0 && event.which === 13) { //13 charCode: ENTER
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addEventDeleteParent(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", deleteNodeOnClick);
}

input.addEventListener("keydown", addListAfterKeyDown);
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
```

```css
.iconX {
    font: normal .7em arial;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #ff0030;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>TODO LIST - IMPORTANT TASKS</h1>
<input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Insert Item">
<button id="buttonInput">Add</button>

<ul>
  <li>None</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to just do `allLi[0].remove();` and not use  `ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);` as well?

Comment: it would be better if you add all the related `HTML` or at least describe what you're doing.

Comment: @Sharon yes, I tried using this condition: allLi[0].innerHTML === "None" so that I can check if the first node has "None" as the text node. Both ways produced the same result.

Comment: @ths I just edited and included all HTML.

Comment: great, that would indeed help us. BTW, do you mind changing your `JavaScript` code if I manage to add an answer ?

Comment: @ths Well, this is my first question on Stackoverflow. I certainly can improve the clarity of the question according to the feedback I receive here.

Comment: `this is not happening as expected` what _is_ happening?

Comment: @LuisFebro as long as you don't get much downvotes your question is pretty clear, but am wondering if you accept making some changes to the code you posted in order to make the to-do list fully functioning or you don't ?

Comment: @Sharon The main issue of this code is the initial element with the text node "None" is not being removed after I add new Items. The expected behavior is load the page with this "None" element. When user add at least 1 item, then removed. If the list is empty, then appears "None" again.

Comment: @ths This code was based on a lesson from a senior developer. He instructed me to write DRY code through function in one of his programming basic JS lessons (although I have already learned some advanced JS, now I am brushing up on the technical side again). I know that is a very fundamental way of writing a code. But I will take your notes about fully functioning codes. I fixed the snippet in my question and now is updated and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why having these much functions when the functionality can be done with only two :

- `addItem(itemText, addDelBtn)`: a function that adds an item to the to-do list. It accepts two arguments :

  - `itemText`: is the text to be shown in the item that is going to be added. Mainly this argument is used on page load in order to add the item with the text `None` and when the to-do list becomes empty once again.
  - `addDelBtn`: a flag that is used to see if a delete `button` should be added or not (in the item). Mainly, this arguments equals `true` when a normal item is added (after pressing the add item `button`) and it equals `false` when adding the item with `None` text.
- `deleteItem(e)`: a function that deletes an item from the to-do list.

  - `e`: the click event that is used to get the parent of the delete button that was pressed in order to delete it from the to-do list.

**The main functionality :**

- an item is added based on the `input`'s text if that text isn't empty (after trimming the text).
- the items that are added after writing in the `input` and pressing the add item `button` have a `button` that is used to delete that item from the to-do list.
- if the to-do list is/becomes empty after deleting items or page load, an item with `None` text is automatically added. This item doesn't have a delete `button` and it'll be delete when a new item is added after pressing the add item `button`.
- if the to-do list is empty and a new item is going to be added, the `None` item will automatically be deleted and that new item becomes the first item in the to-do list.
- items are added at any time with the same logic described above.

Another point, as we have to dynamically create elements (the delete `button`s and the `li`s), I created a function that create an element based on its tag name (`li`, `button`...).

So, here's a demo, it contains a wealth of helpful comments that may assist you while reading the code.

```js
/**
* @const input the "input" on which an item is created based on its value.
* @const button the button that adds a new item.
* @const ul the to-do list.
* @const createElement(tagName, options) a function that create an element and return it.
    @param tagName the element's tag name.
    @param options an object that holds the attributes and/or the events for that element.
* @const deleteItem(e) a function that deletes an element from the to-do list.
    @param e the event (mainly the click event).
* @const addItem(itemText, addDelBtn) a function that adds a new item to the to-do list.
    @param itemText the text for that item (if not specified the input's value is used)
    @param addDelBtn a boolean flag that is used to see wether a delete button should be added to the new item or not.
**/
const input = document.getElementById("userInput"),
  button = document.getElementById("buttonInput"),
  ul = document.getElementById("toDoList"),
  createElement = (tagName, options) => {
    /** creates a new element based on the tagName parameter **/
    const el = document.createElement(tagName);
    /** where in the options object (the second parameter) we should search (it may contao "attributes" and/or "events") **/
    let field = "attributes";
    /** if we have attributes to be added to the new element **/
    if (options["attributes"])
      for (let i in options[field])
        /** apply the attributes **/
        options[field].hasOwnProperty(i) && (el[i] = options[field][i]);
    /** if we have events to be attached to the new element also the "field" value becomes "events" if so **/
    if (options["events"] && (field = "events"))
      for (let i in options[field])
        /** attach the events **/
        options[field].hasOwnProperty(i) &&
        el.addEventListener(i, options[field][i]);
    /** return the newly created element **/
    return el;
  },
  deleteItem = e => {
    /** remove the item where the delete button was pressed based on the "target" attribute of the "event" (e) object **/
    ul.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
    /** if the to-do list becomes empty add an item with the text "None" and without a delete button (see the arguments passed "None" and false) **/
    !ul.firstChild && addItem("None", false);
  },
  addItem = (itemText, addDelBtn) => {
    /** create new "li" using createElement function **/
    const li = createElement("li", {
      attributes: {
        textContent: input.value || itemText
      }
    });
    /** if the first item in the to-do list is the one that has the "None" text delete it **/
    ul.firstChild && ul.firstChild.textContent.toUpperCase() === "NONE" && ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    /** if the input has a value remove that value (the text in it) **/
    input.value && (input.value = "");
    /** if the "addDelBtn" is true then a button that deletes an item is added to the created "li" **/
    addDelBtn &&
      li.appendChild(
        createElement("button", {
          attributes: {
            type: "button",
            innerHTML: "&times;", /** &times; is the entity for X sign**/
            className: "iconX"
          },
          events: {
            click: deleteItem
          }
        })
      );
    /** add that "li" to the to-do list **/
    ul.appendChild(li);
  };

/** attach click event to the add button **/
button.addEventListener("click", () => input.value.trim().length && addItem.call(null, false, true));

/** on page load add a "None" item **/
!ul.firstChild && addItem("None", false);
```

```css
.iconX {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}

.iconX:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1>TODO LIST - IMPORTANT TASKS</h1>
<input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Insert Item">
<button id="buttonInput">Add</button>
<!-- the "ul" tag has an "ID" of "toDoList" to simply select it in the "JavaScipt" part -->
<!-- also it is initially empty and "JavaScript" will add an item with "None" text when the page loads -->
<ul id="toDoList"></ul>
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer and that's the exact behavior I was trying to produce. Just for clarification, I wonder why we use the property hasOwnProperty if we can get the same result without it while looping the elements. I

Comment: @LuisFebro good point, as objects inherit other attributes/methods from other objects (mainly the base `Object` in our case) using the `hasOwnProperty` method we ensure we use only the attributes that were declared explicitly by ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

for future questions please limit the shared code to the relevant portions only.

I hope the following is what you are after:

```
 /**
 * [someFunction description]
 * @param  ul [the target ul]
 * @param   li [the new li element]
 * @return  ul
 */
function populateUl(ul, li) {
    //check if li is only holding the 'none' li
    let ulContent = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")
    if (ulContent.length == 1 && ulContent[0].textcontent) {
        ul.innerHTML = "";
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
    return ul;
}
```